How to serialize properties into separate Json using System.Text.Json in C#?
I am trying to serialize and deserialize a class (say A) into Json.
The class has multiple properties (say X1, X2, X3) which are object instances (of class X) which contains large lists.
public class A
{
    public X X1 { get; set; }

    public X X2 { get; set; }

    public X X3 { get; set; }
}

public class X
{
    // This should request the serializer to put this into a separate file rather than within the parent's json
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool SplitJson { get; set; }

    public List<Y> LargeList { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public List<object> AnotherList { get; set; }
}

public class Temp
{
    public static void JsonTest()
    {
        A a = new()
        {
            X1 = new()
            {
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        AnotherList = ["placeholder"]
                    }
                ],
                SplitJson = true
            },
            X2 = new()
            {
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        AnotherList = ["dummy"]
                    }
                ],
                SplitJson = true
            },
            X3 = new()
            {
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        AnotherList = ["text"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { WriteIndented = true };
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, options));
    }
}

While I can serialize those instances (of class X) individually and load them into my main class (A), I need a way to serialize class A into Json in such a way that its properties (X1 & X2) are serialized into relative file paths ("X1.json" & "X2.json") only when they request so.
For example: This is the normal output
{
  "X1": {
    "LargeList": [
      {
        "AnotherList": [
          "placeholder"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "X2": {
    "LargeList": [
      {
        "AnotherList": [
          "dummy"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "X3": {
    "LargeList": [
      {
        "AnotherList": [
          "text"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

What I need is something like this:
{
  "X1": "X1.json",
  "X2": "X2.json",
  "X3": {
    "LargeList": [
      {
        "AnotherList": [
          "text"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

I need to control the serialization by means of a Boolean property in class X called SplitJson. If enabled the serializer should serialize the instances of X with SplitJson set to true into relative paths. Then those instances of X of those properties should be serialized into the corresponding files. This should also work with deserialization.
Also, are there any ways to implement delayed (or async) setting of properties? I need the class A to load first but the properties with relative paths to json files should not be deserialized until required. But the relative paths to the separate Jsons should be stored somewhere and must deserialize when needed.

I'm fairly sure there is nothing built in for this, you most likely need to split and reassemble your objects yourself, using separate classes for serialization and object model. Also, what is the actual goal? Speed? size? How much data are you storing? Have you considered some binary serialization format if this is a concern?

You can write 2 converters to serialize and deserialize property value as separate file. If you want it async, then you need notification when your object is ready, an event or some methods to await for (to serialize/deserialize).

@JonasH,
I am trying to optimize performance and memory management by reducing the data loaded from the json. I wanted to know if there any means to implement this with JsonConverters. I am not used to custom converters. So, I needed some guidance.
The data is not that big they are just collections of objects which hold collections of objects and so on. The endpoints of each data, point to a csv file. Thus, the json are actually metadata for the csvs.

@Sinatr, I am not familiar with converters. I tried to build one from samples with no success. I needed some code examples for understanding. As for async, I figured out some method. But it would be really helpful if someone could help me learn how to build such a converter. Thank you!

If the data is small, does speed / memory actually matter? Have you done profiling and measurements so that you have a baseline, and know that this is the part of the program most in need of optimization? One approach I sometimes use is a zip-archive used as a container, store large data chunks in some suitable binary format, and use json for metadata.

This is a very weird "optimization" that you are attempting to do here. If the serialization is a bottleneck for you, have you considered just moving to a different transport altogether, like Protobuf? By creating a custom "monster" you are just going to shoot yourself in the foot IMHO.

I think I should explain my use case better. Say I am creating a hierarchical tree of resources with each resources having their own children and parent. I don't want the children (or tree) to be loaded without necessity to reduce the memory usage. If I am to use a normal serializer, that would deserialize all the items in the json in one go and will create unnecessary instances of resources. What I want is, load the top-level resources first and the necessary resource trees. This requires putting their json in a separate file. I am open for any suggestions regarding a better way to do this!

@JonasH I tried loading 10^6 items, it works well in Windows. But for mobile and web platforms the perfomance is very low. I can't do improvements with the slow performance of the UI stack. So, I have to cut off unnecessary memory usage by not loading unnecessary data from the json. I am building an educational app, so performance does matter. And also, I have found the answer. Thank you all for your guidance. If there are any better ways to implement this, please let me know!

@JonasH, I have to use a zip file to transport the whole data. The archive will contain these metadats, CSVs, markdown docs, images, etc. The metadatas (i.e. json) will be loaded first (top level metadata or index) then the resource tree will be populated with children loaded from other jsons. The metadata contain information regarding those CSVs, MD, Images, etc. The zip file will be bundled with the app, unpacked on first run. And subsequent runs will just load from the extracted files. I chose JSON because .NET has built in support for it and it is smaller than XML.

@sinatr, Thank you so much for your guidance!
I was really confused with Json Serialization in System.Text.Json. I thought I would have to write my own converter to handle writing and reading all properties by myself and put into consideration of polymorphism and everything for this. But your approach of using JsonConverterAttribute on properties solved my confusion. If I had to make a JsonConverterFactory or apply the attribute to the class, I would have to write and read the Json manually. But with this I can trick the JsonSerializer to do all the work instead. I also figured out how to make it work with lists.
That being said, I modified your approach to meet my criteria.
Here is my code,
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Symptum.Core.Serialization;

public class Temp
{
    public static void JsonTest()
    {
        A a = new()
        {
            Title = "a",
            X1 = new()
            {
                Title = "x1",
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        Title = "x1-y1",
                        AnotherList = ["placeholder"],
                        SplitMetadata = true,
                    },
                    new()
                    {
                        Title = "x1-y2",
                        AnotherList = ["placeholder"]
                    }
                ],
                SplitMetadata = true
            },
            X2 = new()
            {
                Title = "x2",
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        Title = "x2-y1",
                        AnotherList = ["dummy"]
                    },
                    new()
                    {
                        Title = "x2-y2",
                        AnotherList = ["dummy"]
                    }
                ],
                SplitMetadata = true
            },
            X3 = new()
            {
                Title = "x3",
                LargeList =
                [
                    new()
                    {
                        Title = "x3-y1",
                        AnotherList = ["text"]
                    }
                ]
            }
        };

        JsonSerializerOptions options = new() { WriteIndented = true };
        Debug.Write("\\a.json");
        Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(a, options));
        Debug.Write("\\a.json");
        Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    [Base]
    public X? X1 { get; set; }

    [Base]
    public X? X2 { get; set; }

    [Base]
    public X? X3 { get; set; }
}

public class X : Base
{
    [ListOfBase]
    public List<Y>? LargeList { get; set; }
}

public class Y : Base
{
    public List<string>? AnotherList { get; set; }
}

public class Base
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool SplitMetadata { get; set; } = false;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string? MetadataPath { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsMetadataLoaded { get; set; } = true;
}

public class BaseConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T> where T : Base
{
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
        {
            string json = reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty;
            if (json.StartsWith('\\'))
            {
                string filePath = json;
                Debug.WriteLine(filePath);
                if (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) is T obj)
                {
                    obj.SplitMetadata = true;
                    obj.MetadataPath = filePath;
                    obj.IsMetadataLoaded = false;
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }

        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value == null) return;

        if (value.SplitMetadata)
        {
            string filePath = "\\" + value.Title + ".json";
            writer.WriteStringValue(filePath);
            value.MetadataPath = filePath;
            Debug.Write(filePath + ":");
            Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options));
            Debug.Write(filePath + ":");
            Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
        }
        else
        {
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
        }
    }
}

public class ListOfBaseConverter<TList, TBase> : JsonConverter<TList> where TList : IList<TBase> where TBase : Base
{
    public override TList? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException();
        }

        if (Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert) is TList list)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    return list;
                }

                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
                {
                    string json = reader.GetString() ?? string.Empty;
                    if (json.StartsWith('\\'))
                    {
                        string filePath = json;
                        Debug.WriteLine(filePath);
                        if (Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TBase)) is TBase obj)
                        {
                            obj.SplitMetadata = true;
                            obj.MetadataPath = filePath;
                            obj.IsMetadataLoaded = false;
                            list.Add(obj);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TBase>(ref reader, options) is TBase obj)
                {
                    list.Add(obj);
                }
            }
        }


        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TList value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();

        foreach (TBase item in value)
        {
            if (item == null) return;

            if (item.SplitMetadata)
            {
                string filePath = "\\" + item.Title + ".json";
                writer.WriteStringValue(filePath);
                item.MetadataPath = filePath;
                Debug.Write(filePath + ":");
                Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
                Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(item, options));
                Debug.Write(filePath + ":");
                Debug.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
            }
            else
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, options);
            }
        }

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class BaseAttribute : JsonConverterAttribute
{
    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if (!typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert))
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(BaseConverter<>).MakeGenericType([typeToConvert])) as JsonConverter;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ListOfBaseAttribute : JsonConverterAttribute
{
    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if (!typeToConvert.IsGenericType)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        if (!typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert))
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        Type elementType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (!typeof(Base).IsAssignableFrom(elementType))
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ListOfBaseConverter<,>).MakeGenericType([typeToConvert, elementType])) as JsonConverter;
    }
}

And here is the output:
\a.json--------------------------------------
\x1.json:--------------------------------------
\x1-y1.json:--------------------------------------
{
  "AnotherList": [
    "placeholder"
  ],
  "Title": "x1-y1"
}
\x1-y1.json:--------------------------------------
{
  "LargeList": [
    "\\x1-y1.json",
    {
      "AnotherList": [
        "placeholder"
      ],
      "Title": "x1-y2"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "x1"
}
\x1.json:--------------------------------------
\x2.json:--------------------------------------
{
  "LargeList": [
    {
      "AnotherList": [
        "dummy"
      ],
      "Title": "x2-y1"
    },
    {
      "AnotherList": [
        "dummy"
      ],
      "Title": "x2-y2"
    }
  ],
  "Title": "x2"
}
\x2.json:--------------------------------------
{
  "X1": "\\x1.json",
  "X2": "\\x2.json",
  "X3": {
    "LargeList": [
      {
        "AnotherList": [
          "text"
        ],
        "Title": "x3-y1"
      }
    ],
    "Title": "x3"
  },
  "Title": "a"
}
\a.json--------------------------------------

And as to support delayed loading (that is due to async file operations in UWP). This converter will return an empty instance with only the json file path in MetadataPath.
And this empty instance can then be populated with the loaded json whenever needed. Here is the code for the populate method:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29538#issuecomment-1330494636

You can use json converters to customize produced json and perform custom steps (creating separate json-files in your case).
Just to get you started, here is a converter:
public class XConverter : JsonConverter<X>
{
    public required string FileName { get; init; }

    public override X? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<X>(File.ReadAllText(reader.GetString()));

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, X value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(FileName);
        File.WriteAllText(FileName, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }
}

To pass file name into converter you need to create attribute yourself:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class JsonXConverterAttribute : JsonConverterAttribute
{
    public required string FileName { get; init; }

    public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        if (typeToConvert != typeof(X))
            throw new NotSupportedException("Attribute is only applicable to property of X type");
        return new XConverter { FileName = FileName };
    }
}

Now you can use attribute in your class:
public class A
{
    [JsonXConverter(FileName = "X1.json")]
    public X X1 { get; set; }

    [JsonXConverter(FileName = "X2.json")]
    public X X2 { get; set; }

    [JsonXConverter(FileName = "X3.json")]
    public X X3 { get; set; }
}

And to test we serialize and deserialize:
A a = ... (your code)
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);
Debug.WriteLine(json);
var b = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<A>(json);
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(b.X1));
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(b.X2));
Debug.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(b.X3));

The output:
10:48:54:929    {"X1":"X1.json","X2":"X2.json","X3":"X3.json"}
10:48:54:929    {"LargeList":[{"AnotherList":["placeholder"]}]}
10:48:54:929    {"LargeList":[{"AnotherList":["dummy"]}]}
10:48:54:929    {"LargeList":[{"AnotherList":["text"]}]}

And there should be 3 json-files near executable file.

Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate your approach! But I need an approach that should cover asynchronously deserializing the json (due to the files being read async, UWP Storage APIs) and there should be a way to serialize normally (all the properties in a single json) when the SplitJson is set to false and write them to separate files only when it is set to true.

I have updated my question. I think it will make better sense now. Sorry for not conveying properly.
